# How to make Vim recognize the $PATH of a Node.js installation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, vim

I'm trying ot get Vim  to recognize the `$PATH` of my Node.js installation:

```
/home/alex/nvm/v0.8.8/
```

(I installed node via NVM).

But each time I try to call node or any node-related command:

> echo system('/home/alex/nvm/v0.8.8/bin/jshint --config
>   /home/alex/.jshintrc /home/alex/www/coffeescript/js/script.js')

I get this:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

I'm not very sure what's happening here but I think Vim is looking for node in the wrong directory. Is there any way to fix this?

Should I add node's base directory to the $PATH, or use a symlink? How to do that properly?
(I'm not very familiar with dealing with $PATH).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely want to make a symlink to node from somewhere on your path.  `/usr/bin` would be a good choice.  You could do this with:

```
ln -s /home/alex/nvm/v0.8.8/node /usr/bin/node
```

Assuming that `node` is at `/home/alex/nvm/v0.8.8/node`.  I'm not very familiar with `nvm`; it might be deeper in that directory or named something else.